# Reading CDATA Sections parsing XML in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im working through an example iphone tutorial on parsing the google weather api, The api seems to no longer exist so I have sourced an alternative. The tutorial uses libxml2 and xpath query to parse the xml file. I am succesfully parsing most of the data. The problem I have is that the icons url for the weather symbols are enclosed in CDATA sections:

```
 <weatherIconUrl><![CDATA[http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0010_heavy_rain_showers.png]]></weatherIconUrl>
```

I understand that xpath cannot read items enclosed in CDATA . Is anyway of pulling this data from within the tags?

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816422/how-to-handle-the-cdata-tag-while-parsing-the-xml-file-in-ipad/4818676#4818676

Answer (score 5):

Use `parser:foundCDATA:`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
```

to parse CDATA.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlparserdelegate/1407687-parser

Comment: The OP specified that he is using libxml2. The method suggested above is an NSXMLParser delegate method