# iPhone how to get CDATA attribute using NSXMLParser?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I want to parse from an online XML where the XML is like below:

```
<menu maincategory="![CDATA[Erhverv]]" subcategory="![CDATA[Erhvervsregister]]" category="![CDATA[Akupunktur]]"/>
```

In the function parser didStartElement i used like below:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"menu"]) {
        NSString *maincategory = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"maincategory"];
    }
}
```

The output is like below using %@:

```
attributeDict:{
    category = "![CDATA[Advokater]]";
    maincategory = "![CDATA[Erhverv]]";
    subcategory = "![CDATA[Erhvervsregister]]";
}


2011-05-27 19:20:42.663 XML[62494:840b] maincategory using %s: `ãâå
2011-05-27 19:20:42.663 XML[62494:840b] maincategory using %@: ![CDATA[Erhverv]]
```

But i need the output without the ![CDATA] tag

Can anyone please help me that how can i solve that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible dupe of [Reading CData Sections parsing xml in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851965/reading-cdata-sections-parsing-xml-in-objective-c)

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR SUGGESTION
BUT THATS FOR NODE VALUE 
AND I'M IN NEED OF NODE ![CDATA] PROPERTY IN STRING

Comment: Although not a direct solution; it would be very easy to simply take "![CDATA[" and "]]" off those strings.

Comment: No need to shout.  Have you tried NSString *maincategory = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"maincategory"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"![CDATA[" withString:@""];  You'll also need to replace the trailing ']'.

Comment: Hi Rayfleck,
That works but the problem is that it prints correctly in log using %@ but not using %s.
using %s its showing      `õâ»

Answer (score 0):

I would post process the attributeDict with an `NSRegularExpression` object. For each string in the dictionary, copy it into an NSMutableString (named theString in my code below) and run this code:

```
NSError *theError = nil;
NSRegularExpression *theExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"!\\[CDATA\\[(.*)\\]\\]" options:(NSRegularExpressionOptions)nil error:&theError];
NSUInteger count = [theExpression replaceMatchesInString:theString options:(NSRegularExpressionOptions)nil range:NSMakeRange(0, [theString length]) withTemplate:@"$1"];
```